# Toshiba C55t-A5123 Has no access to UEFI/CSM

Tags: bios

I have a Toshiba C55t-A5123 that had a Windows 10 upgrade installed on to a wiped hard drive. (No going to Settings to revert back to previous OS.)

The CD/DVD drive,(I had changed boot order to look at the Optical drive first), with a Win7 install disk was not recognized at boot up to facilitate a complete new Win7 install over top of the current Win10 OS.

I re-wiped the hard drive and formatted it to NTFS, and then used the disk manager from another laptop to change it to GPT!

When I tried to use my Windows 7 Ultimate DVD to re-install (changed boot order so OD CD\DVD was first) but this C55t wont boot from the DVD! Now this is the same DVD that came with this unit but yet it wont boot the Win7 install DVD!!

I read where THIS Toshiba model (because Toshiba was in cahoots with Microsoft) has no provision in BIOS to switch to from UEFI to CSM, UNLESS the bios was updated to v 1.03 (I think that is the latest version)! I did disable "Secure boot" which was the only associated option!

I then created a GPT UEFI USB memstick with Win7 Ult ISO, which booted fine and installed Win7 Ultimate to the re-GPT'ed 500gb SATA hard drive.

But on reboot after Win7 Ult install the ONLY bootable media device found was the USB Win7 memstick???

This C55t-A5123 will only boot to the memstick and completely bypasses (changed boot order to make HDD first) the GPT HDD that has just had Win7 Ulitmate successfully installed!

If I let it boot to the USB MEM stick it starts the Win& installation all over again!

If I remove the USB MEM stick,  I get "Checking Media" and then "No bootable Device -- please restart system" !

It completely ignores the Win7 install on the 500gb GPT SATA hard drive!

Apparently I still need to update BIOS so I can change UEFI to CSM. But how do I do that when there is no bootable device that contains the "scjev130.exe" executable file?

Is there a way to load/install this BIOS upgrade from a USB memstick?

I find it really reprehensible that such an option was deleted from BIOS choices,  just to make it difficult for a Toshiba user top revert back to windows 7!   That is what I have read anyway!

Thanks in advance for ANY input on how to get this Toshiba to recognize the install and/or how to upgrade the bios from memstick.

Comment: Secure Boot has very nothing to do with UEFI.  Windows 7 fully supports UEFI.  Why do you want to use CSM when your drive is partitioned using GPT?  Secure Boot is only a feature of UEFI, and ALL x86 hardware, it is required for secure Boot to have the capability to be disabled.  Your problems is that you incorrectly created the bootable media.  The only reason the cd would not boot would be that, it didn't contain the required EFI drivers, and thus could not be booted too even with secure Boot disabled (because again secure boot isn't required) but also isn't even supports by Windows 7

Comment: Have you changed *all* needed options, including Secure Boot (off), Legacy BIOS mode (on) and Fast Boot (off)? Some other options are ignored (or hidden) if those are not set correctly.

Comment: ramhound, OK the win7 install dvd doesn't have the efi drivers, correct? Is there a win7 version that does? Or how do i bypass the need for the efi drivers to start a win7 install?  thanks for reply

Comment: dr moishe, there is no provisions in the toshiba's bios (bios version 1.10)to switch to legacy mode or turn off fast boot!  i gather when enough people complained they released a newer bios update version (1.30) that did indeed have the options you mention above! But that bios update exe file need s to be ran from a running OS  . .something i don't have now! Had i known to do what i wanted to do as far as changing bios options, i would have installed the update before wiping win10 from the hard drive! lesson learned for next time!  8^(  thanks for reply

Comment: I made some changes and tried to reload win7 from a bootable memstick as above . . After a failed boot the the error message i get is:  Windows failed to start . . .  File: EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD    Status: 0xc000000d   Info: Error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration file